# Differentiate a log of $L^p$ norm, don't understand this result

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, lp-spaces

**I'm reading [this paper](http://www.uam.es/personal_pas/mbonfort/papers/04p-BG05-JFA.pdf). In it, the authors show this lemma:**

[image]

**And then they prove this lemma**

[image]
[image]

**My question is**: I have no idea how they get the result in Lemma 3.2. Do we not get $$\frac{d}{ds}\log \lVert u(s) \rVert_{r(s)}^{r(s)} = \frac{\frac{d}{ds}\lVert u(s) \rVert_{r(s)}^{r(s)}}{\lVert u(s) \rVert_{r(s)}^{r(s)}}= \frac{\frac{d}{ds}\varphi(r(s),s)}{\lVert u(s) \rVert_{r(s)}^{r(s)}}$$
and then we can plug in Lemma 3.1. But this obviously not agree with the result in Lemma 3.2. Both terms on the RHS are lacking a factor of $\frac{1}{\lVert u(s) \rVert_{r(s)}^{r(s)}}$.

Comment: The formula would be right, if they would have written $\frac d{ds}\|u(s)\|_{r(s)}^{r(s)} = ...$. Somehow the logarithm was not taken into account.

Comment: It seems that Lemma 3.2 is used nowhere in the paper. The results following that follow seem to correctly differentiate the logarithmic terms.

Comment: Even if they had written that I still don't get the second term on the RHS..

Comment: It appears when differentiating also the integrability exponents $r(s)$.

Comment: Ah yes that's right thanks.